# Can't direct a domain to a static page using AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I followed this tutorial H[ow to Point your Domain to an S3 Website Bucket](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/cjn-how-to-point-your-domain-to-s3-website-bucket/) and it works well.

My domain e.g. domain.com points my S3 Bucket bucket.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.

However, the index.html does not show by default e.g. if I use the URL domain.com I get this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>AE243F85AC91D283</RequestId>
<HostId>zAcaxygehDiR1EC6/JJADndO+JlvA7dYSAu+uOL7qWtdDGWLLQ+vGCoqescLUAKLH51/kLD/StM=</HostId>
</Error>
```

However, if I use domain.com/index.html or bucket.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com the index.html page appears.

It's only if I use domain.com instead of the above that it doesn't show.

The bucket has all public permissions.

Comment: Have you specified index.html as index document on the bucket as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did specify it.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error. If you are only interested in showing the index.html page whenever the plain domain.com url is used, then you need to specify index.html as the error page as well.

Alternatively, you can do this with a redirect rule in the box below

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals >
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```